# How to configure Whonix gateway to Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux, whonix

I want to anonymously use Kali Linux in VirtualBox. But VirtualBox's network is also my IP address so I want to use Whonix gateway for my Kali Linux, not Whonix workstation.

How do I configure Whonix gateway in Kali? How to connect Whonix gateway to Kali Linux? What's the command I should use?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have imported the Whonix gateway appliance into VirtualBox, and that it is running. Make note of the non-loopback IP address that is printed in the Whonix terminal.

Open the Network Settings menu for your Kali Linux virtual machine in VirtualBox, and then configure Adapter 1 so that it is enabled and attached to the internal network, called Whonix. Save the setup, and start your Kali VM.

If you are installing the Kali VM for the first time, then select the "Configure network manually" option during Kali setup, and use the Whonix non-loopback IP address that you recorded earlier.

If you are using an existing installation of Kali, then start Kali, and execute the following instructions in the Kali terminal:

1. `ifdown eth0`
2. `nano /etc/resolv.conf`
3. Replace the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` with: `nameserver 10.152.152.10`
4. `nano /etc/network/interfaces`
5. Add the following lines to the end of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

   `iface eth0 inet static
   address 10.152.152.11
   netmask 255.255.192.0
   gateway 10.152.152.10`
6. `ifup eth0`
7. Visit https://check.torproject.org/ from Kali, to verify that your connection is now using Tor via Whonix.

See these articles for detailed instructions and explanations:

1. https://www.alienvault.com/blogs/security-essentials/how-does-whonix-make-kali-linux-anonymous-how-to-prevent-it
2. http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/integrate-whonix-with-kali-linux-to-achieve-anonymity/
3. https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/fully-anonymize-kali-with-tor-whonix-pia-vpn-0180040/

Comment: This is not a [good answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). You should provide the essential parts of the solution in your answer so that when the links go dead the solution is still there for people to see.

Comment: Understood. I can't spare time at the moment, but will gladly do so when the opportunity presents itself. In the mean time, if the community has time, and wants to propose edits with relevant extracts, please go ahead.

Comment: The point is that the community is not here to write good answers on behalf of some of its members :) Some help and guidance is good for new members but writing answers for others does not improve the community. You get reputation for whatever you do here, that's the name of the game.

Comment: Got it. I'll test and summarise the instructions in the linked articles, and then add them to my answer.

Comment: Great! I'll go and upvote your answer after you've done that.:)

Comment: i liked the answer